# Linq to Entities Query Only Recognize Integers

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

My app is EF 5.0 Code First using DbContext.  I've been trying to manipulate (filter & sort) using Linq.  I'm first trying to load a context to Local like:

```
context.mytable.orderby(function a a.somestring).thenby(function b d.someint).load
```

I don't get any error but the string ordering is ignored.  The int sort works.  Similarly when I try to set my binding source the linq portions comparing strings or dates doesn't work but when I use integers it works.  I assume these are not converting to SQL query correctly but I can't figure out how to fix them.  I would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: Do you just need ordering to present the data in your UI with a specific order?

Comment: Can you give us some sample data to show us what the ordering problem is?

Comment: Manos - Yes.  I am using Where clauses and Order clauses to get data for display to user.  I'm having the same problem with Where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Load() however doesn't create anything, it only takes a bunch of items and loads them from the underlying source to your context. You can't impose ordering on context.mytable because mytable doesn't hold the actual data, it holds part of the query you'll be using to get the actual data.

To get ordering to your UI you need to either order the list you'll be binding to, or use an unordered list and wrap it in an object whose job is to apply ordering. Since you're using Local go with the later and use [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx).

Here's an example of CollectionViewSource in WPF. It's bound to the property StateOrProvinces of the DataContext that is the unordered list I want displayed in order:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="stateOrProvinceViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=StateOrProvinces}" >
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

with scm being:

```
xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
```

The same thing in code:

```
 CollectionViewSource orderedView = new CollectionViewSource()
     {
         Source = StateOrProvinces,
     };
 orderedView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Using an extra layer to apply ordering has a few advantages. It lets you display the same list with different ordering in different places and you add/remove items from the underlying list without having to manually apply ordering every time.

You should also look at [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview) class that has some extra bells and whistles but I wont go into it, to cut down on info overload.